# Вывод всех значений в цикле

Tags: массивы, php, циклы

Доброго времени суток! У меня такая проблема. Есть массив такой например (многоуровневый):

```
$mas = array ( "города"  => array ( "a" => "Москва",
                                       "b" => "Питер",
                                       "c" => "Самара"
                                     ),
                  "числа"   => array ( 1,
                                       2,
                                       3,
                                       4,
                                       5,
                                       6
                                     ),
                  "прочее"   => array (      "первая",
                                       5 => "вторая",
                                            "третья"
                                     )
                );

echo $mas["прочее"][5];    // напечатает "вторая"
echo $mas["города"]["a"]; // напечатает "Москва"
```

И надо в цикле вывести все ключи и значения его, например в тег echo. Почитал в интернете про рекурсии, говорят это будет медленно работать, если массив будет большой и многоуровневый. Решил воспользоваться функцией array_walk_recursive. Только есть сомнения насчет ее использования, как использовать и будет ли это корректно.

Делаю примерно так:

```
function echo_mas($item, $key) 
{
    echo "$key = $item\n <br/>";
}

array_walk_recursive($mas, 'echo_mas');
```

Как думаете я правильно составил код и верно ли использовать `array_walk_recursive` в этом случае? Проблема в том, что эта функция выводит только внутренние значения, а основной массив с ключами "города", "числа" и "прочее" игнорируются и не выводятся... Как решить эту проблему?

Пока этот код выводит следующее:

```
   a = Москва 
    b = Питер 
    c = Самара 
    0 = 1 
    1 = 2 
    2 = 3 
    3 = 4 
    4 = 5 
    5 = 6 
    0 = первая 
    5 = вторая 
    6 = третья
```

Comment: попробовал ваш код, он обходит только "листья"

Comment: если у вас элементов в массиве меньше десятка тысяч, то можете без сомнения использовать обычную рекурсию, разницы в производительности не заметите.

Comment: см. пример #1 в документации по [``array_walk_recursive()``](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php):
> Любой ключ, содержащий значение типа array, не будет передаваться в функцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот реализация на JavaScript:

```
function Dump(d,l) 
{
    if (l == null) l = 1;
    var s = '';
    if (typeof(d) == "object") 
    {
        s += typeof(d) + " {\n";
        for (var k in d) 
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) s += "  ";
            s += k + ": " + Dump(d[k],l+1);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < l-1; i++) 
            s += "  ";
        s += "}\n"
    } 
    else 
    {
        s += "" + d + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Тут рекурсия используется, что естественно при большом массиве будет медленно работать. Я хотел без нее обойтись. Ну да ладно, все равно спасибо! Только есть два вопроса что за переменная l? Уровень вложения? И есть ли аналог на php функции typeof проверяющая массив ли это или нет? Потому что мне не на js, а на php надо это реализовать.

Comment: @IntegralAL, [``is_array()``](http://www.php.net/is_array)

Comment: переменная 'l' - уровень вложения
на JavaScript; все - объекты; функция проверяет, является элемент объектом
как решать эту проблему без рекурсий, я не знаю, хотя есть предположения.
так же есть вопрос: что есть большой массив? большая вложенность?

Answer (score 2):

[RecursiveArrayIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php), [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
function dump_it($array) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($array),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    );

    foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
        echo "{$key} => {$value}<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Кому лень смотреть доки, подскажу два интересных фокуса:  

 - [RecursiveIteratorIterator::setMaxDepth()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.setmaxdepth.php) - ограничить глубину обхода
 - [RecursiveIteratorIterator::getDepth()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.getdepth.php) - текущая глубина (можно красиво сделать отступы)

Answer (score 0):

У вас 2 уровня вложенности почему-бы не использовать вложенные циклы?

```
foreach($mas as $firstKey => $value){
    echo "<p>{$firstKey} =";
    foreach ($value as $key => $val){
        echo "{$key} = {$val}";
```

firstKey - сюда попадут ключи первого массива
key - сюда попадут ключи вложенного массива
Попробуйте так, зачем-же рекурсия в такой пустяковой задаче.